# Querying Elasticsearch using array of values

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I index items in elasticsearch where in each item has these properties:

```
tags - array of strings eg. [ 'c++', 'java', 'python' ]
submitter_id - uuid
id - uuid
```

Also i have user who has these properties:

```
tags - array of strings 
following_ids - array of uuids
```

What i want to do is query elasticsearch for items where tags match tags of the user or submitter_id is one of user's following_ids, also i boost fields. Right now i form the query like this

```
"should"=>[{"match"=>{"tags"=>{"query"=>"yoga", "boost"=>3}}}, {"match"=>{"tags"=>{"query"=>"yogic technique", "boost"=>3}}},
{"match"=>{"tags"=>{"query"=>"lag jaa gale", "boost"=>3}}},  {"match"=>{"tags"=>{"query"=>"jonita gandhiband", "boost"=>3}}}
{"match"=>{"submitter_id"=>"fc8b720f-a306-4849-8bc1-38fafae7c92b"}},
{"match"=>{"submitter_id"=>"c35ec42f-2df0-4870-89a4-9e59c9df04ea"}}]
```

But if the user has a lot of tags or following_ids, i would soon run into maximum clauses limit. How should i handle this ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're looking for the exact ids and tags you should be using the [Terms Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html) anyway but the added advantage for you in this case is that it allows you to give multiple terms so you would only need 1 clause for all your tags and 1 for your user ids.